# converting the sum of numbers to logarithms

Tags: calculus, probability, logarithms

If I have three number, $[0.2, 0.3, 0.4]$ then I can take the sum simply by adding the term: $0.2+0.3+0.4=0.9$. The proportion of the first element is then $0.2/0.9 = 2/9$.

Now I don't know what the three numbers are but I do know the logarithms (which are so small I cannot take the exponentiation of it). How can I get the proportion of the elements?

So given: $[-1.6094,   -1.2040,   -0.9163]$, how do I find out that the first component has a proportion of $2/9$?

Comment: Do you mean to say that what you have there is $\ln a, \ln b, \ln c$ and you want to know $\frac a{a + b + c}$?

Comment: yes! :) and unfortunately the logarithms are too small to convert ($ln(a) \approx -1000$)

Comment: It might make things worse, depending on the sizes of the numbers, but you could look at differences.  For example, $-1.6094-(-1.2040)\approx\ln(.2/.3)$

Answer (score -2):

If this is a practical problem then note you can use an arbitrary precision floating point library ( [like MFPR , which is free](http://www.mpfr.org/) ) to write a short application to do the exponentiation and addition and division to any precision you care to.

Comment: Imagine a world where down voters explained why they down voted ...